# vscode cant ssh connect "The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe"

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am able to ssh on my windows 10 computer using ubuntu subsystem when I run the command:

```
/mnt/c/Users/marti/Downloads$ sudo ssh -i credfile.pem ec2-user@3.333.33.333
```

Where I have a file located at `/mnt/c/Users/marti/Downloads/credfile.pem`

I am trying to get VSCode's ssh extension to work but it keeps failing with an error "The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe"

In my vscode settings it points to my ssh config file:
[image]

In order to connect I click the green bottom left corner of my vscode window and select the first option 'remote-ssh connect current window to host'

[image]

I paste in my command, hit enter, it prompts me to choose either mac/win/linux and I pick linux.

[image]

But it then just leads to an error saying it tried to write to a nonexistent pipe?

```
[20:50:27.876] "install" terminal command done
[20:50:27.877] Install terminal quit with output: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[20:50:27.877] Received install output: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[20:50:27.883] Resolver error: Error: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe
```

Is there something else I need to setup or change for my vscode ssh connection to work?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of pasting your command, you should code the same command in your `.ssh/config` file.
Add in it:

```
Host ec2
   Hostname 3.333.33.333
   User ec2-user
   IdentityFile C:\path\to\credfile.pem
```

Then you will be able to select the entry '`ec2`' after selecting '`remote-ssh connect current window to host`'