# Resolver error: Error: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote

I followed [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_connect-to-a-remote-host) to connect SSH to my host, but when I have written the command ssh user@hostname, the following error appears:

```
Resolver error: Error: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe
    at Function.Offline (c:\Users\Mushlih\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.4\out\extension.js:1:64692)
    at c:\Users\Mushlih\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.4\out\extension.js:1:62242
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\Mushlih\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.4\out\extension.js:1:62620)
    at Object.t.tryInstall (c:\Users\Mushlih\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.4\out\extension.js:1:413984)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async c:\Users\Mushlih\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.4\out\extension.js:1:294518
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\Mushlih\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.4\out\extension.js:1:405329)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\Mushlih\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.4\out\extension.js:1:295639)
    at async c:\Users\Mushlih\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.4\out\extension.js:127:110530
```

I have read [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60335069/vscode-remote-connection-error-the-process-tried-to-write-to-a-nonexistent-pipe), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65193292/vscode-cant-ssh-connect-the-process-tried-to-write-to-a-nonexistent-pipe), and also [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_troubleshooting-hanging-or-failing-connections) but it didn't work to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

- make sure your remote server has secured by public-private key encrypted.
  if it is, then you must have private key in your local computer
- then follow the process in [this link](https://letswp.io/remote-development-visual-studio-code-amazon-ec2/)